# Customised Bottom Tab Navigator in React-Native

Tags: css, react-native, bottomnavigationview

I have tried developing the bottom tab navigator in React Native but I couldn't develop the screen as shown in the pic. How can I create cap to the middle button. I'm getting a straight line for the bottom navigator . Please help me out with this

Link for the [image is](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/32739276/32442591-8e8bc392-c32e-11e7-83c8-5a1c57d86ef3.png)

Comment: Did you get any solution for this

Comment: Were you able to design such??? I also have to design similar